# How to set the NetBeans Server in Maven?

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans

I have a Web Application that is environment independent so it's a single war that can be deployed to multiple environments.

I have created multiple Tomcat Servers (i.e. Devel, QA, Production) and defined them in in the NetBeans server configuration.

I'm able to run the war against each of the environments fine by manually changing the project properties but I would like to be able to set what server to connect to from within Maven and either add custom Debug/Run actions or by using maven profiles.

I've tried setting:

```
<netbeans.deployment.server.id>tomcat70:home=C:\Apache\Tomcat\7.0.34,base=C:\Apache\Tomcat\Devel</netbeans.deployment.server.id>
```

but that didn't work for me.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to do this is to setup separate profiles in your pom and then have the property set in each of those profiles.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm planning on doing. Maybe I need to rephrase my question above, I'm trying to find out what property needs to be set.